# Powering and injecting 2200 LEDs

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip

I am seeking advice/validation for powering a long length of LED strips. I know it's a lot of questions so I'm grateful for any feedback on any of this.

I'm planning to run about 37m of strip lights around the perimeter under a deck as such:

[image: Layout]

- Strip: **[SK6812](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2757/p2757_SK6812RGBW_REV01.pdf) 60led/m (5V)** as I want addressable RGB+W.  As far as I can tell nothing similar in higher voltage, so needs to be 5V.
- 37m total * 60 LEDs/m = **2200 LEDs**
- [Seller published](https://www.btf-lighting.com/collections/pixels-led-strip-1/products/1-sk6812-rgbw-4-in-1-pixels-individual-addressable-led-strip-dc5v) max power draw for 60/m is 18W/m, so 37 * 18 = **666W** (I've seen [actual measurements](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-L0YvDVq_V17lLOeBc-H19np4wcSLqI6X5i6OAOGoaM/edit#gid=0) that suggest more like 15W/m or 555W)
- PSUs/controller will be inside house near point **A** in diagram

My general plan would be to use multiple power supplies and separate run(s) to inject where necessary. I realize this may be a little over the top for 5V but hoping it's feasible.  If it's too crazy I could fall back to 30LED/m and cut it in almost in half, but would ideally like to do something like this if possible.

**Questions:**

1. Are my power calculations correct and does 666W represent total wattage required from PSUs?
2. How many power supplies and would a unit(s) like [Meanwell RPS-320](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=RSP-320) suffice?
3. At what intervals would I need to inject (to get max white)?  I've read as much as every 2.5m
4. What size wire for separate injector?
5. Any advice on cabling to optimally hit injection points based on the layout?
6. Any advice on making the connections to injection points?  Do  I have to cut the injector line and solder both ends to points on the strip?
7. How do I calculate current draw on the circuit powering the PSUs.  If it's 120/15A circuit how much capacity would be needed max?
8. Is it an omen that my power requirements for this just happen to be 666W?

Thanks!

Comment: For something like this my gut feeling says I'd want 20 separate power supplies (one for each 2m point, supplying 1m in each direction, left and right) and I'd run mains voltages to each node. That reduces the wiring cost/size/etc. It also distributes the heat dissipation for the DC supplies and keeps the load very close to the supply itself. But I'd need to think more about that and would need to see how small and cheap 30W LED COTS supplies might be or what I'd need to design one, cheaper and smaller while still safe. I guess I'd sit down and do a custom design. Others may have better ideas.

Comment: Its more of a packaging problem than an electrical problem. If you have a number of smaller psus, then you need to distribute mains and put them in a weathertight enclosure. Having one or two big psus means you need to contend with voltage drops. Decide which is the bigger evil. Note that these leds at full brightness are freakin bright! You might want to do tests to determine how bright you want and measure the current. Switchmode psus are constant wattage. Watts in = Watts out * loss. Loss is around 10-15%. Depends on psu.

Comment: Are these shift register LEDs? with 2200 and a long run you won't get an awesome refresh rate with just one driver.